# Double fourier series in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, symbolic-math

I'd like to plot a mesh for both `f` and `g` functions below in MATLAB:
[image: f and it's double Fourier series g]

I'd tried this for `f` and `g`:

```
%% plot f
[x,y] = meshgrid(linspace(-pi,pi,50));
f = x.*y ;
subplot(1,2,1)
mesh(f)
title('f')

%% plot g
syms  m n
A = 4*(-1)^(m+n)*(sin(m*x)*sin(n*y))/(m*n);
g = symsum(symsum(A,n,1,inf),m,1,inf);
subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(g)
title('g')
```

The result of `mesh` is:

[image: the result of mesh]

The section plotting `f` is running without any error. The other section plotting `g` show nothing in the figure. How can I plot `g`?

Comment: it's not a code error.sorry,I've corrected my question.

Comment: Why are you using symbolic math for `g`? Just don't do that, you can't plot symbols anyway.

Comment: so how could I define summation without symsum?

Comment: You're trying to go to infinity, that'll take infinitely long. Write a `for` loop and quit at a certain order of `n` and `m` and see how closely the result resembles.

Comment: would anyone help me to write the `for` loops, I'm tired and completely confused with this code, sorry

Comment: No, as Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Simply loop over both `m` and `n` and sum in the end over both dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to work with symbolic math, it's a good idea to get comfortable with [assumptions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assumptions-for-symbolic-objects.html), especially when dealing with periodic functions and functions with discontinuities. You may also want to use [`fmesh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fmesh.html) (or `ezmesh` in older versions) to plot meshes of symbolic expressions:

```
syms m n x y
assume(in(m,'integer') & m>=1);
assume(in(n,'integer') & n>=1);
assume(x>-pi & x<pi);
assume(y>-pi & y<pi);
A = 4*(-1)^(m+n)*(sin(m*x)*sin(n*y))/(m*n);

g = symsum(symsum(A,n,1,Inf),m,1,Inf);
fmesh(g,5*[-pi pi -pi pi],'MeshDensity',1e2); % or ezmesh(g,5*[-pi pi -pi pi]);
```

This creates a plot like this:
[image: fmesh plot]

Another option is to evaluate `g` numerically using [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) and [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) and then use `mesh` to plot:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-5*pi,5*pi,100));
g2 = real(double(subs(g,{x,y},{X,Y})));
mesh(g2);
```

or use [`matlabFunction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to create a numeric function:

```
g2 = matlabFunction(g);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-5*pi,5*pi,100));
mesh(real(g2(X,Y)));
```

In both these latter cases, `real` must be used to clip the insignificant imaginary parts due to numerical imprecision.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want the explicit way to do it with a `for` loop, here it is:

```
XY = 2*linspace(-pi,pi,50);
N = 100;
M = 100;
G = zeros(numel(XY));
tmp = zeros(M*N,1);
cx = 1;
for x = XY
    cy = 1;
    for y = XY
        c = 1;
        for m = 1:M
            for n = 1:N
                tmp(c) = 4*(-1)^(m+n)*(sin(m*x)*sin(n*y))/(m*n);
                c = c+1;
            end
        end
        G(cx,cy) = sum(tmp);
        cy = cy+1;
    end
    cx = cx+1;
end
mesh(G)
title('g')
```

And this is a bit more compact way, which should be faster:

```
XY = 2*linspace(-pi,pi,50);
N = 100;
M = 100;
G = zeros(numel(XY));
cx = 1;
for x = XY
    cy = 1;
    for y = XY
        gfun = @(m,n) 4.*(-1).^(m+n).*(sin(m.*x).*sin(n.*y))./(m.*n);
        tmp = bsxfun(gfun,(1:M).',1:N);
        G(cx,cy) = sum(tmp(:));
        cy = cy+1;
    end
    cx = cx+1;
end
mesh(G)
```

and the result:

[image: fourier]